# Is this language in R, RE or coRE? or neither $ L=\{\langle M\rangle\mid M$ is a TM that accepts all even length words$\}$

Tags: formal-languages, computability

in my quest to understand computability theory, I came across this question, and it made me think that I don't fully understand the theory

is this language in R RE or coRE? or neither
$$ L=\{ <M>|M \ Is \  a  \ TM  \ that \ accepts \  all \  even \ length \  words \} $$

my attempt:

in terms of where intuition this language is in coRE because we can only reject input that is not in the language, which is a TM that accepts an odd lengh word. but i am not sure how to make the reduction from $$ \overline{HP} $$

Comment: this is the question from the text book @Nathaniel I need to know how to do the reduction from $\overline{HP}$

Comment: What $M$ does on words of odd length has no impact at all on whether $\langle M \rangle \in L$ or not.

Comment: What is $\overline{HP}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your intuition about this language being co-semi-decidable is incorrect, since whether some word of odd length is accepted makes no difference on whether the Turing machine belongs to the language. To prove that a Turing machine is not in $L$, you need to show that it does *not* accept some *even* length word. There isn't an obvious semi-algorithm to do that: you can always run it and if it rejects, you will see it, but it might not terminate, and you will never be sure.

In fact, this language is neither semi-decidable, nor co-semi-decidable (and in particular not decidable).

Perhaps the easiest to show is that $L$ is not decidable. This follows immediately from a famous result, [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem). (If you want an explicit reduction from the halting problem, I encourage you to look at the proof of Rice's theorem.)

To show that $L$ is not semi-decidable, you can apply a less famous but also very useful sibling of Rice's theorem, namely the [Rice-Shapiro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%E2%80%93Shapiro_theorem). See the Wikipedia page for a precise statement. A machine that accepts all words is in $L$, and by the Rice-Shapiro theorem, this entails that some machine which only terminates on a finite number of words is in $L$, a contradiction since there are infinitely many words of even length.

The proof that $L$ is not co-semi-decidable can also be done with the same theorem. A machine that always loops is not in $L$, and terminates on a finite number of words (namely zero), therefore *any* machine must not be in $L$, because all machines "extend" this looping machine in terms of behavior. This is absurd, because some machines are in $L$.